# Peewee join query can't get data

Tags: peewee

I have the following 2 tables in my database.

```
tbl_customers
cid (int auto)
name (text)

tbl_contacts
cid
email
name
phone
```

I am trying to write the following sql query in peewee, but just can't get it to work

```
SELECT tbl_customers.cid, tbl_contacts.name
FROM tbl_customers
INNER JOIN tbl_contacts ON tbl_customers.cid = tbl_contacts.cid
WHERE tbl_customers.cid = '5';
```

I am trying to get the data to display like this

```
tbl_customer.cid = 5
tbl_contacts.name = 'Test User'
```

I tried the following in peewee, based on google searches that i am finding.

```
tbl_customers.select(tbl_customers.cid, tbl_contacts.name).join(tbl_contacts, on=(tbl_customers.cid == tbl_contacts.cid)).where(tbl_customers.cid == '5')
```

Answer (score 1):

Peewee automatically puts your models into a graph, so the contact name would be accessed something like:

```
customer.contact.name
```

If you just want all data on a single model instance, you can append ".objects()" to your query and it will put all the column data on the instance-type being selected.

This is documented thoroughly:

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/relationships.html#selecting-from-multiple-sources

Comment: Thank you for your response, but something that doesn't make sense, when i print out the query that peewee is doing, and i take that same exact query and put it in sqlite3 it gives the right data back. But for some reason in peewee it doesn't not sure why

Comment: If you read my comment and the linked document, hopefully that will clarify things..